# How to mock IProcess to in a c# Unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, autofac

I have a C# method I want to mock the return value of in a unit test. My test infrastructure uses Autofac and AutoMock for dependency inversion/injection.

```
public System.Diagnostics.Abstractions.IProcess GetClientIProcess(int ProcessId)
{
    var temp = Process.GetProcessById(ProcessId);
    System.Diagnostics.Abstractions.IProcess clientIProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Abstractions.Process(temp);
    return clientIProcess;
}
```

All I want to achieve is to mock the return value here so that it will return a valid IProcess that is used in the real method that I am testing in my unit test

Comment: Any time you call `new .....` you can't really mock anything. You could make an interface called, for example `IProcessProvider` that has a method that returns an `IProcess`. So you can inject a mock of that instead.

Comment: Okay well I can just using casting for that

Comment: Is this `GetClientIProcess` method part of that dependency which is used by the to-be-tested code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Moq to create a [Test Double](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) version of `IProcess`, you'd create an object in your test code in this way:

```
var processTD = new Mock<IProcess>();
```

and then somehow pass `processTD.Object` to your System Under Test (SUT).

The `processTD.Object` object will be a particular implementation of `IProcess` with test-specific behaviour, specified by the test code. Only that object will have that behaviour. This object's concrete type is an auto-emitted class that implements the `IProcess` interface.

This (simplified) line of code in the current SUT:

```
IProcess clientIProcess = new Process(temp);
```

creates and returns a `Process` object. The `Process` class also implements the `IProcess` interface, but it is *not* a Moq object, and neither can you change it to become a Moq object as long as you `new` it up as `Process`.

If you want to test using Moq, you'll have to figure out how to hook into the SUT in a way that enables you to replace one `IProcess` object with another.

A common way to do that is via Dependency Injection, but you could also use a design pattern like [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).